# How do I add x-amz-acl:public-read to an Amazon S3 Secure Url

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**My scenario:** I need to generate a secure url to hand to a client. That client will use the url to post a file directly to S3. The file should then be available to the public.

I am currently trying to figure out all the moving parts via unit test. I am using the [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox) module's implementation to generate secure URLs.

Here is my test:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs'),
    knox = require('knox'),
    request = require('request'),
    config = require('../config');

var s3 = new knox.createClient({
    key     : config.aws.accessKey,
    secret  : config.aws.secretKey,
    bucket  : 'poopdart'
});

exports.url_generation = {
    put_object: function(test) {
        var file = '/foo/' + new Date().valueOf() + '.json';

        var qs = {
            'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
        };
        var signedUrl = s3.signedUrl(file, new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000), {
            verb: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json'
//            qs: qs
        });

        console.log(signedUrl);

        var body = JSON.stringify({ date: new Date() });

        var options = {
                url: signedUrl,
                method: 'PUT',
                body: body,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Length': body.length,
                    'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
                    }
                };

        request(options, function (err, response, data) {
            if(response.statusCode !== 200) console.log(data);
            test.equals(response.statusCode, 200);

            request.get('https://print-template-images.s3.amazonaws.com' + file, function (err, response, data) {
                test.equals(response.statusCode, 200);  // fails with 403
                test.done();
            });
        });
    }
};
```

**Note:** If i add the x-amz-acl header to my post request the key validation fails. If I add it to the querystring of the signed url it is ignored and the file is left private.

Anyone have pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want all files in this bucket(or bucket prefix) to be publically readable?

Instead of setting authorization in the request you can use a bucket policy: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=185968#185968

Comment: be warned that an open bucket policy means anyone can list the contents of your bucket (and you get charged for the listing). Be sure and block that with a permissions statement.